# How to do something when children are set?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following one to many model.

```
class Person(Base):
    id
    things = relationship('Thing')

    def some_magic_here():
        pass
class Thing(Base):
    id
    person_id = ForeignKey(person.id)
```

What I want to achieve is, when I do the following:

```
p = Person()
thing1 = Thing()
thing2 = Thing()
p.things = [thing1, thing2]
```

method `some_magic_here` will function to do some work processing thing1 and thing2 before they are added as children

Comment: Wouldn't `p.things = [thing1, thing2]` just overwrite the `things` property of `Person`?

Comment: @aIKid Is there a way to override this default behavior?

Comment: Well.. What do you want, actually? I think you're confusing yourself a bit here. Read the sqlalchemy docs, there's a tutorial on how to make a one-to-many relationship

Comment: @aIKid eg. originally, p.things = [Thing(id=1, new desk)]. then when i set p.things = [Thing(id=2, new desk)], some magic will be called, check Thing(id=2) and return telling there is already a similar desk

Comment: When you set `p.things=anything` the previous value will be overwritten!

Answer (score 0):

You want the event system: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append

e.g. something like:

```
@listens_for(Person.things, 'append')
def some_magic_here(target, value, initiator):
    # do whatever
```